# fields from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an output temporary table created with a sql stored procedure. it will list total days for types of insurances listing them in seperate fields
here is the abbreviate version:

```
patient insurance qtydays
AAA       MCare     19
AAA       MCaid     07
AAA       Private   21
```

what id like to see is the following:

```
patient MCaredays MCaidDays PrivateDays
AAA         19        07        21
```

Im guessing PIVOT would work but cant get it to work
any help is appreciated!

Comment: I second @Pரதீப்'s question, you'd logically want to `group by` patient and then create a new `insurance_nameDay` field that's a sum of the insurance days. But if there's an indefinite numbers of insurances I have no clue of how to do it. (There's obviously a way, but not that I know of)

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this;

```
SELECT patient, MCare, MCaid,Private
FROM (
SELECT patient, insurance, qtydays
FROM YourTable) up
PIVOT (SUM(qtydays) FOR insurance IN (MCare, MCaid, Private)) AS pvt
```